# When i try to upload files to my web server it doesnt work but if upload them locally it works

Tags: php, html, iis

I'm trying to upload files to be more precise images from my web-pages to my webserve but it doesn't work. If i do it locally everything works fine but on the Server it doesn't work. 
It doesn't give me out any Error message and i don't know why either.

I've tried to give the right permissions and it didn't work it. I tried another way to program it and it didn't work either. It always shows my first else-loop.

```
<?php
$SBA_ID = $_GET['SBA_ID'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$file = $_FILES['my_file'];
print_r($file);
$fileName = $_FILES['my_file']['name'];
$fileTmpName = $_FILES['my_file']['tmp_name'];
$fileSize = $_FILES['my_file']['size'];
$fileError = $_FILES['my_file']['error'];
$fileType = $_FILES['my_file']['type'];

$fileExt = explode('.', $fileName); 
$fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

$allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf'); 

if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
if ($fileError === 0) {
if($fileSize < 1000000){
$fileNameNew = "Auftrag".$SBA_ID.".".$fileActualExt;
$fileDestination = 'AuftragFotos/'.$fileNameNew;
move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
header("refresh:2;url= ../Startseite.php");
}else {
echo "Your File is too big!";
}
}else {
echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
}
}else {
echo "You cannot uplaod files of this Type";
}
}
```

**My Form**

```
<form action="<?php echo"speichern/Fotospeichern.php?SBA_ID=$SBA_ID"?>"        
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_file"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

I expect the output to be that the Image is uploaded to the "AuftragFotos" Dir but it always shows: "You cannot upload files of this Type" even though i specified that Type of file to uploaded.

Comment: Activate error reporting to see if a error appears: `ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Show us the result of `print_r($file);`

Comment: @CodyKL still doesnt appear any errors.

Comment: @04FS On the local server it shows me the result but on the live server it doesnt print out anything no even if its Null

Comment: How about the content of `print_r($file)`?

Comment: If there is no `$_FILES['my_file']` you have to check what your form looks like.

Comment: How about `print_r($FILES)` instead of `print_r($file)`?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I update the question so yo see my Form

Comment: @CodyKL It still doesnt show anything..

Comment: Put `var_dump($_FILES);` at the very start of your script, before any `if` conditions that might not be fulfilled to begin with, and see what you get.

Comment: You have a problem with string escaping. Also you mix GET with POST!
See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with string escaping.

Change:

```html
<form action="<?php echo "speichern/Fotospeichern.php?SBA_ID=$SBA_ID"?>"        
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_file"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

to:

```html
<form action="speichern/Fotospeichern.php?SBA_ID=<?php echo $SBA_ID; ?>"        
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="my_file"/>
<button type="submit" name="submit">UPLOAD</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Well spotted! You can combine `$_GET` and `$_POST`, that's not the problem, the quotes were. I think. I never put `<?php` ... `?>` inside HTML tags anyway because they are confusing to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answere but now i dont get anything not even my echo saying that i cant upload the file.

Comment: True @KIKOSoftware but it's bad practice to use GET and POST.
GET should be used for getting data from a website and POST when you send data to a site/script.

Comment: I agree that in this case it would make sense to only use `$_POST`, I just wanted to say that it's not the root cause of the code not working. Ah, and now you've changed your code.

Comment: Yes, cause I'm sure that he use the SBA_ID in the URL as a parameter when he comes from a other sub page. I've seen already a few projects like that from german photografs :(